# Integrating directive in Angular UI Modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qs0VonyAzINK7MjMQhji?p=preview) I have the following:

- A control object shared between the controller and the directive.
- The directive declares a method in the control object.
- The controller invokes the  method to set a value.
- The directive is included in an Angular UI Modal.

For some reason the control object is empty when the modal is opened (look at the console log). How to invoke the method from the controller to set the field value?

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtl">

        <button ng-click="openModal()">Open modal</button>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">The Title</h4>
            </div>

            <ddl control="ddlControl"></ddl>                

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>

       </script>

    </div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,$uibModal) {

        $scope.ddlControl = {};

        $scope.openModal = function() {
          $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
              templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
              scope: $scope
            }); 

          console.log($scope.ddlControl);
          $scope.ddlControl.set();

        };
})

.directive('ddl', function () {

    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'EA';
    directive.scope = {
         control: '='
    };
    directive.template = '<div>someValue: {{someValue}}</div>';
    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.control = scope.control || {};

        scope.control.set = function() {
           scope.someValue = 1;
        };

    };
    return directive;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a race condition between opening the modal and running a digest of the modal HTML.

When the button is clicked `$scope.openModal()` is executed. The modal opens and gets into the digest phase. But javascript is not waiting until the digesting has been completed, so it continues executing `$scope.openModal()` until the end.

You need to handle the promise of $uibModal.open().rendered(). The uibModal resolves the `rendered` promise when it's done.

```
    $scope.openModal = function() {
      $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          scope: $scope
        }).rendered.then(function() {
             console.log($scope.ddlControl);
             $scope.ddlControl.set(); 
        }); 
    };
```

The $uibModal.open() function returns the following:

`Object {result: Promise, opened: Promise, rendered: Promise}`

In the promise block of `rendered`, you can safely make use of the fields that has been changed by the directive.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/GnIThstxkuR06felh8Pe?p=preview